# How to display values in sql from a specific order?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column courses from school table which contains:

courses:

```
Art
History
Science
Math
Physical Education
```

course_code:

```
ASM201
HISU3
BIO302
MDM4U
P.E
```

I am trying to show only the courses after Science.
I have :

```
Select courses
from school
where courses > 'Art';
```

but it's giving me errors.It keeps repeating one course name more than 10x
   .does < or > work the same to strings?

Comment: you need to share your code, for better information

Comment: There needs to be some other column to identify the order

Comment: @Prdp I added it.

Comment: @aok - Even that is not useful. Do you have `created date` or `auto generated` column ?

Comment: no I don't have. I just created the table manually.

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense. What tables do you have? What columns do they contain? In your query you select from table `school` only. A table called `school` or `schools` should contain exactly this: schools. One record per school with the name, the address, the type maybe. It would not contain courses. And what does course_code have to do with this? Is this yet another table? Or another column in the same table? What does it have to do with the task? Show your tables and columns and some sample data what they contain.

Comment: Then a completely different matter: what is "courses after Science" supposed to mean? A table contains a set of data, nothing more. There is no inherent order. Are you talking about "after Science" in the alphabet? Or the classes taught right "after Science"? Or what? How can "courses after **Science**" mean "courses > '**Art**'"? Please show tables with sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`Syntax: Select column_name from table_name GROUP BY column_name HAVING operator value`

In your case the query will be

> Select Course from School group by Course HAVING Course > 'Art';

Comment: In Oracle, this should work. In MySQL, you don't need to do this. select subject from (select 'History' subject union select 'Art' union select 'Pol Sci' union select 'Math') t where subject > 'Art'; will work just fine.